# Spring Boot Request Header Size unit-test validation

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, unit-testing

In my Sprint Boot `3.2.0` service, I have added the following in my `application.yml` file:

```yaml
server:
  port: 3001
  max-http-request-header-size: 36000
```

This will increase the allowed request header size.

Now I have written unit-tests to verify if the server is actually allowing this to work:

```kotlin
import com.myproject.account.functional.FunctionalTest
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status
import java.util.*

class HeaderSizeMvcTest : FunctionalTest() {

    @Test
    fun `Request with large header should be accepted`() {
        val largeHeader = generateLargeString(35900)
        println("Size of largeHeader: ${largeHeader.toByteArray().size} bytes")
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/502?token=A999")
            .contentType(contentType)
            .header("Large-Header", largeHeader))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Request with too large header should be rejected`() {
        val tooLargeHeader = generateLargeString(150000)
        println("Size of tooLargeHeader: ${tooLargeHeader.toByteArray().size} bytes")
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/502?token=A999")
            .contentType(contentType)
            .header("Too-Large-Header", tooLargeHeader))
            .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError) // Expect a 4xx error (e.g., 431 Request Header Fields Too Large)
    }

    private fun generateLargeString(size: Int): String {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ByteArray(size))
    }

}
```

The `FunctionalTest` is an abstract class:

```kotlin
package com.myproject.account.functional

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.ResponseTemplateTransformer
import com.myproject.account.Application
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import java.nio.charset.Charset


@SpringBootTest(classes = [(Application::class)])
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("functional", "swagger")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
abstract class FunctionalTest {

    protected val contentType = MediaType(
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.type,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.subtype,
        Charset.forName("utf8")
    )
    @Autowired
    protected lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    companion object {
        private var wireMockServer: WireMockServer? = null
        @BeforeAll
        @JvmStatic
        fun proxyToWireMock() {
            WireMock.configureFor(8089)
            wireMockServer = WireMockServer(
                wireMockConfig()
                    .port(8089)
                    .extensions(ResponseTemplateTransformer(false))
            )
            wireMockServer?.start()
        }

        @AfterAll
        @JvmStatic
        fun noMoreWireMock() {
            wireMockServer?.stop()
            wireMockServer = null
        }
    }

    init {
        TestContextManager(this.javaClass).prepareTestInstance(this)
    }
}
```

But for some reason both the tests are returning `200` response, so seems like I am not able reproduce request header too large issue at all on my local. What should I update?